# Padding missing from div

Tags: css, html, padding

I've created a mobile friendly site but I'm having a minor problem when the page is displayed at low resolutions, such as on a mobile.

http://designated.net.au/testbed/djdais/

As you can see it looks fine in full screen, but at low resolution it looks like this:

[image]

There is 5px of padding missing from the bottom of the menu, even though I have defined it in the CSS.

Here is my code:

```
/* =Menu
-------------------------------------------------------------- */

#access {
background: #333; /* Show a solid color for older browsers */
clear: both;
display: block;
float: left;
margin: 0 auto 6px;
min-width: 300px;
max-width: 880px;
min-height: 50px;
border: solid;
border-width: 10px;
border-color: #666;
padding: 0;
text-transform: uppercase;
}
#access ul {
font-size: 14px;
line-height: 30px;
list-style: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 5px;
}
#access li {
float: left;
position: relative;
margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
width: 135px;
height: 30px;
text-align: center;
background: #666;
}
```

Comment: Add `overflow:auto` to your `ul`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a float on your #access ul

Try this:

```
#access ul {
font-size: 14px;
line-height: 30px;
list-style: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 5px;
float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the padding from the access `ul {}` and apply it to the `access div` instead

Answer (score 0):

```
#access {
background: #333; /* Show a solid color for older browsers */
clear: both;
display: block;
float: left;
margin: 0 auto 6px;
min-width: 300px;
max-width: 880px;
min-height: 50px;
border: solid;
border-width: 10px;
border-color: #666;
padding: 5px;
text-transform: uppercase;
}

#access ul {
font-size: 14px;
line-height: 30px;
list-style: none;
margin: 0;
}
```

Try this. Remove padding from #access ul & apply padding to #access.